# How to split string on operator(s) (/*+-)

Tags: kotlin

I am making an android calculator and trying to get it to split the string when it encounters an operator (for example "*"). However, `val one` returns the entire string **20x20** instead of **20**.

```
fun main() {
    var equation = "20*20"
    val splitValue = equation.split("[/*-+]")
    var one = splitValue[0]
    println(one)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `split` in Java, [`split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) in Kotlin does not treat the string that you pass to it as a regular expression. `split` in Kotlin takes one of these things:

- a `Regex` object
- a list of `String` delimiters, passed as varargs
- a list of `Char` delimiters, passed as varargs

So you can either do:

```
equation.split("[/*\\-+]".toRegex()) // toRegex creates a Regex object
```

(Note that it is important that you escape the `-` in the regex. Otherwise, itt means "from...to" (`*-+` means all the characters from `*` to `+`), and the string will be split on more characters than you would expect.)

or

```
equation.split('/', '*', '+', '-')
```

Comment: "*Note that it is important that you put - as the last delimiter in the regex*". I mean, for this reason, I think it's safer just to escape it, even if it's last. You never know who might introduce an additional operator onto the end in the future. That's the kind of bug that can waste a lot of time to find. If you can mitigate that by making your regex minutely longer, I'd say do it.

Comment: @Michael Good point. I didn't consider that.

Comment: Thank you! Would this logic apply to the .contains() function as well, or could you pass in ```"[/*+-]"```?

Comment: @KidRonee `contains` can take in a `Regex`, so you can pass in `"[/*+-]".toRegex()`. If you just do `"[/*+-]"`, then it will *literally* try to find the substring `"[/*+-]"`.